# Crystal Reports Data Source in Oracle

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, oracle11g

I inherited a legacy system using Crystal Reports in VS.NET pulling info from an Oracle11g DB.

The database fields are in "REPORT_DATA", I updated the stored procedure which the code is querying to add a field, however I cannot see that new field in the field explorer.

When I click on "Verify Database" and manage to log into the DB I get a "Remove Table" prompt - "The database table "REPORT_DATA" cannot be found. Proceed to remove this table from the report?"

Of course, there is no REPORT_DATA table and there never was.

When I preview the report or put it on the server it works, so there is some behind-the-scenes magic which I don't understand.

Comment: If you look at the query the report uses, is it using fully qualified table names?

http://wisdomofsolomon.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/crystal-reports-tables-not-found-during-verify-database/

Comment: Right, it's changed. How do I get the new field to show up under Database Fields?

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, but do you have rights to alter the database table and actually add the field to the table?

Comment: Yes I do, already done that.
If I "reconnect" I lose all the data but I see my new field.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I had to highlight the server name in the “Current Data Source” area and the name of the server in the “Replace With” area on the Set Datasource Location window.  Then click the “Update” button.

Since the report wasn't built on my machine it had to be reconfigured - can't figure out why it still connected to the DB when previewing though.